# How to pass value to a custom-annotation?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

My query is this. Say, i have a custom annotation as follows:

```
                    //rest of the code left out for the sake of brevity
                    interface @Name{
                        String myName();
                    }
```

Now, in the class where am using this annotation on say, a field or a method, i want to **pass a value to "myName" from a property file**, something like this:

```
                    @Name(myName="${read.my.name}")
                    public void something(){}
```

Could anyone please suggest how can i read the value passed to 'myName' in my annotation-processor from the property file? I have read a bit about the use of placeholders and then using @Value but am not sure i can/should use this approach in say, a service class where i just want to have an annotated field or method marked with this annotation? Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 4):

Here's my method-level annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Name {

    public String myName();

}
```

Here's a dummy class that declares the annotation:

```
public class Z {

    @Name(myName = "George")
    public void something() {

    }
}
```

Here's how to get the value:

```
final Method method = Z.class.getMethod("something");
if (method.isAnnotationPresent(Name.class)) {
    final Annotation annotation = method.getAnnotation(Name.class);
    final Name name = (Name) annotation;
    System.out.println(name.myName()); // Prints George
}
```

Comment: Well, I do not want to pass @Name(myName="George"). I want to have "George" stored in a property file say under 'property.name.george' and then pass it something like @Name(myName="${property.name.george}") And then in my annotation-processor i should be able to read the value stored in 'property.name.george as "George". Hope i could clarify the requirement.

Comment: So i came up with a sort of hack to work around it; posting it here for the reference of anyone in future. Since the posted requirement wants the property value to be read which happens at runtime and annotations are processed as compile time; so in my beanpostprocessor am simply extracting the value passed to 'myName' and reading from the properties file just as one reads in the usual circumstances.

Comment: I am having the same requirement. I need to get the value from property file at compile time and pass the same annotation processor. Can I have same reference how to do it in beanpostprocessor and set it to the custom annotation